# how to forward a message from the bot(not a person) to a chat

Tags: python, telegram, telepot

I want to forward the whole conversation of my bot and another person to myself

This is my code:

```
import telepot
bot = telepot.Bot('<Token>')
def handle(msg):
    my_id = 123456789    # this is my id for example
    chat_id = telepot.glance(msg)[2]
    bot_msg = bot.sendMessage(chat_id, 'this message is sent by bot')
    bot.forwardMessage(my_id, bot_msg['from']['id'], bot_msg['message_id']) # this line gets error
```

But when I try to forward messages from bot I get this error:

```
telepot.exception.TelegramError: ('Bad Request: message to forward not found', 400, {'ok': False, 'error_code': 400, 'description': 'Bad Request: message to forward not found'})
```

Am I doing somthing wrong?
or It's just restricted by telegram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second param to forward should be originating chat id, not user id.
Try calling:

bot.forwardMessage(my_id, bot_msg['chat']['id'], bot_msg['message_id'])

Comment: yes it works.thanks
but I thought the chat_id is the id of the person who is chatting with the bot

Comment: glad it helps. can you please accept answer? thanks.